# Touch not working on android apps running on ARC

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I have a laptop running windows 8.1 with a touch enabled screen.
I am using arc to run apk on the laptop.
The touch works fine on ARC welder but after launching apk, the touch event does not work on app's screen. Just the mouse event works.
I have tried multiple apks and everyone behaves same.

Do we have to enable something to make the touch events work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has been reported here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480745

Answer (score 0):

So a way of getting around this at least for map applications is to specifically code the APK to handle the event and you must use the Arc-Metadata tag of
`"enableSynthesizeTouchEventsOnWheel": false`, this stops the runtime from trying to interpret your scroll wheel as a touch instead of the `SOURCE_CLASS` it is.

So for the input device `SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER`, you have to define `ACTION_SCROLL` so that a mouse scroll wheel will allow you to do actions. There is plenty of examples of how to do this all over StackOverflow though, just disable that meta-tag and most of the code you normally use for making things work in Android will work here.

Note: Haven't tried `"enableSynthesizeTouchEventsOnClick": false`, and testing with `SOURCE_` that equals a external touchscreen but i believe it would work .